# Need tutorial help for layouts

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a sample of a layout that I would like to do on a specific size of paper and I need all of the professional layout tips and tricks I can get. I have a sample drawn up of what the finished product should be, as well as the notations and trimmings that need done to lay it all out properly. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's as simple as pointing me towards a link that has a tutorial on how to layout print documents. I work for a print shop and this is the kind of work their graphics department deals with, mainly. I'm just curious and like to learn as many skills as I can to hopefully get a good job in graphics.  Thanks in advance for any help that is offered.

[image]

Comment: This is way too broad. (And kind of insulting, if you ask me, to assume to master graphic design you only need a handful of tricks up your sleeve.) The most important facts are missing from your brief: who is the target audience? for what use? what units are these? is this a book, a brochure, a package, a leaflet, a poster, a sleeve, or something else? how is it going to be reproduced?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're question is... What exactly are you asking? Asking for "tips and tricks" is probably too broad for Stack Exchange by the way, but I'm not even sure what you want tips and tricks for. Please take the time to go through the [Help] and [ask] pages and try and make your question a bit clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I was asking if anyone knew of any tutorials or even a book that I could learn the program with. thanks for the help....smh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am after a certain look or layout I design a custom grid. It can look just like your sketches above, the areas of art defined with boxes.

Draw the grid and keep it alone in the top layer in illustrator. Toggle visibility to output graphics or to see it cleanly.

While you should make the custom grid for the one particular layout, you should have a standard grid under that. The lines can be a different color to tell them apart.

All formal digital and print text/graphic content is based on a grid. Everything lines up. Nothing doesn't line up. Make the grid for 1, 2 or 3 columns with equal space between each. Define a header and footer in your grid, define the print borders (edges) if necessary.

Make a grid for 8.5" x 11" flyers, one for postcards, one for posters etc.

Remember you can make a rectangle the full size of your print then scale down like 5% to make an inset border.

The grid can be drawn with the rectangle tool, the line tool, or make a covering grid by drawing a filled square and using "split into grid", define your rows and columns, check if you like it and choose no fill, stroke of .5.

Lock the grid alone in the top layer so it will be visible above everything else.

When aligning shapes or text zoom all the way in and drag or tap that shape right up to the line.

Grid is how you get clean layout, next you need to learn about theming, hierarchy of information and design in general.

Comment: Thank you for the point in the right direction, this was honestly very helpful for my mindset when approaching this little project. I was mostly having trouble with where I should make my first point of attack, if that makes sense? Your answer helped a lot in that regard, so thank you much!  =)

Comment: Hey you are totally welcome. I am very happy to teach. If theres anything else you need to know just ask.  I have experience with design for print and digital.